# Creating a chained installation using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wix, nsis

I have created a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) C# application. But I am facing problems in creating a setup for my application.

My problem is

1. I want to install the prerequisites as a chain of installers with a common progress bar.

   1. .NET Framework 3.5
   2. [SQL Server Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) SP2 (optional, that is, install only if SQL Server is not installed)
   3. [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) redistributable package.

All these prerequisites must be embedded in the setup file. I have created a bootstrapper to install the SQL Server Express Edition if it not already installed.

1. After installation, it should update the `exe.config` file with the connection string datasource with the SQL Server Express Edition instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3 to bootstrap prerequisites quite easily. [Here is an explanation showing how to do it for .NET 3.5 and Windows Installer.](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm)

You should be able to use the same principle for SQL Server Express Edition and Crystal Reports.